# NAT/Masquerade. Was working before, now is not

Tags: networking, rhel, iptables, nat, cluster

So for at least two months I had an IP tables configuration that was working on a compute cluster to provide internet access to compute nodes that were technically offline, via the headnode. We recently had to reboot the headnode which I'm almost entirely certain flushed out whatever setting was making it work. I was able to fetch a backup of /sysconfig/iptables and was wondering why iptables-restore using this file wasn't working... Here are the contents of that backup...

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed May  9 09:36:22 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1:36]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1294:196435]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 372 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 372 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp7s0f1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp7s0f0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp7s0f0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.103.182.0/24 -i enp7s0f0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.103.182.0/24 -i enp7s0f0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp7s0f0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 8649 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 40000 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -i enp7s0f0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 0:1023 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -i enp7s0f0 -p udp -m udp --dport 0:1023 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i enp7s0f0 -o enp7s0f1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp7s0f1 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed May  9 09:36:22 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed May  9 09:36:22 2018
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [19:1852]
:INPUT ACCEPT [11:1496]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [18:1302]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [16:1110]
-A POSTROUTING -o enp7s0f0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed May  9 09:36:22 2018
```

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Note: enp7s0f0 is external, public interface and enp7s0f1 is internal private interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `iptables` configuration looks sane, but have you checked the master switch of IPv4 forwarding?

Try this command:

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

If it says `net.ipv4_ip_forward = 0` instead, then IPv4 forwarding has not been enabled. That's easy to fix:

```
# echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >>/etc/sysctl.conf
# sysctl -p
```

This will enable IPv4 forwarding in a persistent manner. (Previously, IPv4 forwarding may have been enabled by something like `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`, which won't persist over a reboot.)

Comment: Stumbled on this soon after I had my issue, but your solution is still the correct fix. Thanks for the comment!